# P4Python - getting affected files given changelist number

Tags: perforce, p4python

so far I have been using p4.run("files", "@=" + ) to find the affected files per CL. However, I'm having the issue that for certain CLs the output shows 'no files found'. When I run the p4 files with the same CL in my command line it shows that there are files. Any ideas as to why this is happening or if there is an alternate way to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: If you get two different answers from the same command, it usually means that you're running it against two different servers (or with users that have different permissions, etc).  Double-check the port, client, and user of your script against the settings shown by `p4 info` in the CLI.

Comment: Could they be shelved by a different user?